# MongoDB Auth, can be authenticated in the shell but not via the command line

Tags: database, mongodb, database-administration

I have an application that connects to a MongoDB database called discussions. I've created a user

Mongo shell:

```
> use discussions
switched to db discussions
> db.auth("discussions","XXXXXXXXX")
1
> show users
{
        "_id" : "discussions.discussions",
        "user" : "discussions",
        "db" : "discussions",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "discussions"
                }
        ]
}
```

So that is to confirm that I do have one account on the database and it's a dbOwner. According to the docs it has READ, WRITE, etc privileges.

The configuration file has the property "auth = true" enabled, and the service has been bounced since the change, more than once.

However, the problem is that when I attempt to connect to the database from outside of the shell I always get the error:

```
mongo  discussions -u 'discussions' -p 'XXXXXXXXX'
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: discussion
2014-08-05T01:00:39.026+0400 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

I've seen questions on Stackoverflow about this and they all had something to do with the quotes used around the username and password... but changing the single quote to a double quote didn't yield a better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing any symbols. It appears that despite quotes [single or double] would cause the incoming password to be invalid.

Comment: In my case, I tried to connect with mongoose and I wasted 2 hours because of my database name had an underscore

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm wrong but the correct form is like this:

mongo --port 27017 -u manager -p 12345678 --authenticationDatabase admin

You can read about this in mongo documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/

Comment: The default is 27017 for port. Also the authenticationDatabase has the discussions user to be valid on admin and the "discussions" database.